# Interfaces with default values?

Tags: angular

Bit of confusion here, so my understanding of interfaces from tutorials I've read is that they should be used as a blueprint for a type/object. Say I have a Person interface, and I want to use it in a component, how would I create an instance of it with some defaults, age/dob for instance?

Comment: You cannot create instance of an interface- it's just type information and doesn't compile to JavaScript. You have to create a class if you want it to have default values.

Comment: Then you would require a class that implements an interface. https://johnpapa.net/typescriptpost3/

Answer (score 0):

In your case , you'd need an abstract class .

```
 export abstract class MyAbstractClass{

   public myvalue = 'something';
  }
```

You cannot have values in an interface and reason is the interface is something in Typescript world and after the transpilation , it would completely disappear